# Not able to check the radio button selected value in custom validation using mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, customvalidator

I have got the radio button list in my view like below..

**View:**

```
  <div class="deleteControls">
    <div class="labelHead">@Html.Label("Delete")</div>
    <div class="controlsAndLabels">@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Submit,  MVC.Models.SubmitAction.DeleteItem) @Html.Label("Delete By Item")</div>
    <div class="controlsAndLabels">@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Submit, MVC.Models.SubmitAction.DeleteVendor)  @Html.Label("Delete By Vendor")</div>
    <div class="controlsAndLabels" style="padding-left: 20px;">@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.IsCancelPageChecked, "Cancel Page") @Html.Label("Cancel Page")</div>
    <div class="controlsAndLabels">@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Submit, MVC.Models.SubmitAction.DeleteMember) @Html.Label("Delete By Member")</div>
 </div>
```

and this is my model for that view where I am defining property for radio button

**Model:**

```
    public SubmitAction Submit { get; set; }
    public bool IsCancelPageChecked { get; set; }

    [DeleteByItemValidator("ByItem")]
    [Display(Name = "By Item")]
    public string ByItem { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "By Vendor")]
    public string ByVendor { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "By Member")]
    public string ByMember { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Cancel Page")]
    public string CancelPage { get; set; }
```

and this enum for binding radio button list

```
public enum SubmitAction
{
    DeleteItem,
    DeleteVendor,
    DeleteMember

}
```

I am doing custom validation on server side using custom validator like this below

```
 public class DeleteByItemValidator : ValidationAttribute
 {
    public string DeleteByItemRadioButton { get; set; }

    public DeleteByItemValidator(string deleteByItemRadioButton)
    {
        this.DeleteByItemRadioButton = deleteByItemRadioButton;
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object currentValue, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (IsRadionButtonSelected(validationContext, DeleteByItemRadioButton))
        {
            // here I am doing validaions
        }
        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }

    // this method is giving always false even if i selected one radio button 
    private bool IsRadionButtonSelected(ValidationContext validationContext, string PropertyToSelect)
    {
        Type iType = validationContext.ObjectInstance.GetType();
        object RadioButtonSelectedValue = iType.GetProperty(PropertyToSelect).GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null);//here I am getting null value 
        bool isChecked = Convert.ToBoolean(RadioButtonSelectedValue);
        return isChecked;
    }
}
```

My problem is that I am not checking the whether the radio button is selected or not and this method is returning false value even if I selected radio button

```
 private bool IsRadionButtonSelected(ValidationContext validationContext, string PropertyToSelect)`
```

Is this way is correct to validate the radio button selection or is there any other approach please suggest any ideas.

Would any one have any idea how to check whether the radio button is selected or not

Many thanks In advance

Comment: Would any one have pls suggest any idea about this ....

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you try to validate that a radio button is checked. Why don't you add the `[Required]` attribute to the `public SubmitAction Submit { get; set; }` property and remove the `IsRadionButtonSelected` method?

Comment: yes try to validate the radio button,if i remove that how can i pass the current radio button selected item to validator method

Comment: @pratapk This [page](http://dotnetspeak.com/2012/05/validating-dependent-fields-in-asp-net-mvc) helped me in a similar case.

Comment: but it does not contain Radio button list ..... in my case i  have got three radio buttons and one submit button, if i select first radio button and then press the submit button i need to show corresponding error message on view ...

Answer (score 0):

You validator code is correct where you access the property. It is null because you are not using the ByItem in your View. Also instead of a string use a boolean. That should work.

Update:

```
   @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.ByItem,  Model.ByItem) @Html.Label("Delete By Item")

    [DeleteByItemValidator("ByItem")]
    [Display(Name = "By Item")]
    public bool ByItem { get; set; }
```

Comment: I have 4 more radio buttons in that view in that case is this code works that u have specified in view ...

Comment: yeah, I don't think you need a custom validator unless you have special requirement. In you post action something like   (!model.ByItem)
    ModelState.AddModelError("ByItem", "ByItem not selected");

Comment: u can see my enum in that model in the view i am using that enum ....if the user is selected i need to do some validations with the data coming from database .. i think for this i need to do custom validation ...

Comment: 4 radio buttons. I think you should give them boolean values and should work.

Comment: with out using Boolean with this approach is it possible to check selected item .......

Answer (score 0):

I would do it without custom validators. Example:

Model

```
public class Test3Model
{
    [Required]
    public SubmitAction  Submit { get; set; }
    public bool IsCancelPageChecked { get; set; }

}

public enum SubmitAction
{
    None,
    ByItem,
    ByVendor,
    ByMember 
}
```

View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Test3","Form"))
{
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Submit, SubmitAction.ByItem, Model.Submit== SubmitAction.ByItem ? new { Checked = "checked" } : null)
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Submit, SubmitAction.ByVendor, Model.Submit== SubmitAction.ByVendor ? new { Checked = "checked" } : null ) 
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Submit, SubmitAction.ByMember, Model.Submit== SubmitAction.ByMember ? new { Checked = "checked" } : null ) 


    @Html.ValidationSummary();
    <input type="submit"/>
}
```

Controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Test3(Test3Model model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid && model.Submit != SubmitAction.None)
        {
            //some actions
        }

        return View("Test3", model); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it, the only property that is set on your object is Submit , ByItem, etc.. are never used.  You can remove them I think and change the custom validator to work with Submit property only.